# python - Beautiful soup - get specific value in html not standard tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Fairly new to beautiful soup. Trying to parse this tag

html

```
<score-bill scoreA="86" audiencestate="upright" data-qa="score-panel" data-scoresmanager="scorebill:scoreAction" id="scoreboard" mediatype="assetseries" rating="" skeleton="panel" scoreb="98" assetstate="active">
```

Desired Results

```
86
```

Question

How do I parse the value in this tag?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the tag with `find`

```
html = '<score-bill scoreA="86" audiencestate="upright" data-qa="score-panel" data-scoresmanager="scorebill:scoreAction" id="scoreboard" mediatype="assetseries" rating="" skeleton="panel" scoreb="98" assetstate="active">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
results = soup.find('score-bill')['scorea']
print(results) # 86
```